# "group by day" in Oracle doesn't appear to group by date

Tags: oracle, date

My query looks something like this:

```
select datesent, count(*) the_count from receivedmessaged where status=5000
and datesent>(to_date('20130101', 'YYYYMMDD')) group by datesent
```

What I'm looking for is a table that has the count of messages with a status of 5000 per day, newer than a certain date. What I'm getting is a table with the same dates over and over. What I think is happening is that there is a hidden time part in that datesent field, and its grouping the entries by the exact time they were sent, rather than just looking at the date. Can anyone confirm this and tell me how I can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: From the above we can assume the type of `datesent` column is `date` as you compare it to return value of `to_date` function. There is no hidden time part in `date` data type but the time component is essential part of the type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What I think is happening is that there is a hidden time part in that datesent field, and its grouping the entries by the exact time they were sent, rather than just looking at the date.

That's very probably what's happening. So try that:

```
select TRUNC(datesent), count(*) the_count from receivedmessaged where status=5000
and datesent>(to_date('20130101', 'YYYYMMDD')) group by TRUNC(datesent)
```

`TRUNC` will remove the "time part" and allow you to group by *day*.

---

Please note that the use of `TRUNC` wil invalidate your index. Take a look at your execution plan. And if needed, you should add a [function-based index](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/function-based-indexes.php) on `TRUNC(datesend)`.

Comment: I've been yelled at for trying to use trunc before, because of indexing issues. I'm assuming this will be fine because I'm only truncing the results?

Comment: I don't know how exactly are indexed you table. But maybe you should consider using a [`function-based index`](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/function-based-indexes.php) ?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, using `TRUNC` would solve your issue, and using a `function-based index` would make it efficient.

However, from `11g` onwards, you could also use `VIRTUAL colums`. In your case, you can add a virtual column as `new_date ALWAYS GENERATED AS (TRUNC(date_column))`. You just need to use this virtual column in your query. For performance improvement, if required, you could create an index.

***NOTE : Indexes defined against virtual columns are equivalent to function-based indexes.***

Comment: +1 Adding a `VIRTUAL` column is definitively a good idea if the OP has access/is allowed to modify the schema.

Comment: Yes, OP should have the required privilege.